# Using pointer to a Global function

Tags: c++, class, pointer, typedef

I am trying to store and use a pointer to a global function.
The function ***global_f*** returns a String and takes an object as parameter:

```
String global_f(Request r){
    // ...
    return "This is it";
}
```

I have also declared a type:

```
typedef String (*f_type)(Request);
```

And this is the class that stores the function:

```
class T {
    f_type f;

    void setF(f_type fFunc){ // called as: setF(&global_f)
        f = fFunc;
        f(Request());        // This Works
    }

    void callF(){
        f(Request());       // This Freezes the arduino
    }
}
```

So I can call ***f*** in the instructor, but it freezes the Arduino in other methods.

***Follow-up:*** It runs in all methods, that the function is being passed as a parameter and stored in the object.
This is where this functions is called in the actual code: [GitHub](https://github.com/kachatzis/ArduinoWebServer/blob/758ba6eae7ab1a9fccdbdb3606bdfbfa980be742/lib/EthernetWeb/src/ApiEndpoint.cpp#L47)

Comment: `//called as: T(&global_f)`? it should be `T(global_f)`

Comment: how do you know it is freezing the Arduino? or even working in the first case? You don't do anything with the return value in either case!; can you make a complete, minimal sketch that shows the problem?

Comment: @Juraj I tried both of them and they give the same results, also PlatformIO compiles both

Comment: @esoterik I am using Serial.print to know how it runs. This is just the most important part of the code for this problem. I can provide a link to github if it is needed.

Comment: the snippets are OK. the problem is in the code you didn't show

Comment: @Juraj This is the actual code I'm using https://github.com/kachatzis/ArduinoWebServer/blob/758ba6eae7ab1a9fccdbdb3606bdfbfa980be742/lib/EthernetWeb/src/ApiEndpoint.cpp#L47